# Excel - highlight a specific number between even or odd

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I was not able to find a solution to the following task:

I need to highlight all numbers (in this case the number was "5") between two even numbers on the left and right in a large selection of cells (example below). It is obvious I can do this manually, but is there a way to do this automatically with a formula or condition formatting?

[image: example]

Comment: Your example does not make sense. There are `5`s that are highlighted that are **not** between 2 even numbers.

Comment: Hi David, I haven't actually highlighted the 5s. Additionally, the table is just a random representation of a small selection from a larger data base. I need to highlight the 5s located between 2 even numbers. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why not highlight the 3?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DavidPostill♦ that the example you provided does not make sense in terms of the formatting, but based on your comment, the following solution would work using conditional formatting (assuming your data is stored in the range `A1:F7`).

Go to cell `B1` -> `Conditional Formatting` -> `New Rule...` -> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. Here you can enter the following formula:

```
=AND(B1=5,ISEVEN(A1),ISEVEN(C1),C1<>"")
```

The `AND()` function is used to determine if all conditions are TRUE. The first element checks if your number is actually 5, the second and third elements check if the numbers are even, and finally the fourth element makes sure that the 5 in the last column is not highlighted because the element to its right is empty.

Subsequently, press `Format...` and select the `Font style: Bold`. Press `OK` and then use the format painter to apply the same conditional formatting to all cells in the range `B1:F7`, respectively.

The final output looks as follows:
[image: output]

Comment: Thank you, sir!